# RecyclerView items shown only when user clicks on searchView

Tags: android, android-fragments, orm, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerView, but items (stored in database) are shown only when user click on searchView in toolbar, after that items in recycler view are normally shown. I am little bit confused about that.

Can you help me please?

Fragment

```
//list init

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        database = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        database = SugarRecord.listAll(ContactORM.class);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        mAdapter = new ContactsAdapter(getContext(), database);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Adapter

```
class ContactsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    List<ContactORM> database;
    ContactORM contactORM;
    Context mContext;

    public ContactsAdapter(Context context, List<ContactORM> contacts) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.database = contacts;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int type) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_item_contact, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.avatar) CircleImageView avatar;
        @BindView(R.id.name) TextView name;

        public ViewHolder(View rowView) {
            super(rowView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, rowView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        contactORM = database.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());

        if ((contactORM.getLastname() != null)) {
            holder.name.setText(contactORM.getName() + " " + contactORM.getLastname());
        } else {
            holder.name.setText(contactORM.getName());
        }
        //if photo is not null, load image
        if (!(contactORM.getPhoto() == null)) {
            Picasso.with(mContext).load(contactORM.getPhoto()).resize(100, 100).into(holder.avatar);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return database.size();
    }
}
```

XML layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context=".ui.contacts.ContactsFragment">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- starts custom searchView -->
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_search_white_24px"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/search"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="9"
                    android:hint="@string/search_contact"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/ib_clearText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_clear_white_18px"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <!-- end custom searchView -->

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

        <!-- floating action button -->
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24px"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: what is your exact question, sorry but I couldn't get it.

Comment: you need to update your recycler view adapter when search view clicked, according to your requirement if the user  either move out from search view or clicked on items(stored in database) then update the recycler with normal data.

Comment: No, I don't need a searchView. My problem is that items aren't shown when fragment is alive, but only when I click on searchView. I want them to show immediately when fragment is alive.

Comment: @Rajendra So fragment is blank (should be filled of items) and when I click on searchView, it is filled - that is the issue I have

Comment: Post your XML please.

Comment: I eddited my post